# sas macro variable not resolved

Tags: macros, sas, global-variables

I have a problem with a code that used to work (like one week ago)
and now on a new computer, it doesn't anyomore

I create my macro variables with SQL

```
proc sql noprint;    
select count(distinct(num_nation)) into :nb_country  from AFGp
;
%let nb_country = &nb_country;
select distinct(num_nation) into :pays1 - :pays&nb_country from AFGp;
select count(*) into :nbvar from variables;

%let nbvar=&nbvar;

select variable, var_label, lbl_categ into :var1 - :var&nbvar, :lab1 - :lab&nbvar, :labc1 - :labc&nbvar from variables
;
quit;
run;
```

and this macro does not recognise the macro variables starting with var :

```
%macro testtest();

%do j = 1 %to %eval(&nb_country);

    %do i = 2 %to %eval(&nbvar);
        proc freq data=AFGp noprint;
            tables &&var&i. / nocol nocum nofreq nowarn out=_TFP_&j._&i;
            where num_nation = &j;
        run;
        %end;
    %end;

%mend;
```

For instance :
this

```
%let j=4;
%put &j &var4 &&var&j;
```

returns this:

```
4 Female &&var4
```

This code used to be resolved normally, and I don't understand why it doesn't anyomore.

If you could help me, or even put me on the right direction, this has blocked me for 3 hours now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax issues can get the parser mixed up, and you need to run the magic string (as [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33474262/open-code-statement-recursion-detected-during-exporting-a-file) by Joe) to reset:

```
%*;*;*';*";%*%mend;*);
```

This might not be an issue with your code - it can be triggered (eg in Base SAS) by highlighting and running a 'partial' code block.

Comment: Thanks ! This will definitely help if I come accross that again. As for the missing ; it disappeared when I pasted the code (overwrote). It was in the code, i didnt have a warning

Comment: Have updated my answer to omit the part about the `;`.  Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

I restarted SAS, and now the same code works.

I still have no idea why it didn't work before or even if this is a reccuring problem for some but apparently the SAS motto is "when in doubt restart!"

Comment: Sometimes you get an unclosed quote, macro definition, or something else that masks the macro facility.  Restarting is the easiest way to solve it.

Comment: Thank you. It will help in the future !